# Ошибка при закрытии приложения

Tags: android, java

Доброго дня. Пишу приложение по работе с блютус. При закрытии приложения происходит его краш. Помогите понять почему.

```
          h = new Handler() {
          public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
          switch (msg.what) {
          case RECIEVE_MESSAGE:                                                   // если приняли сообщение в Handler
            byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
            String strIncom = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);
            sb.append(strIncom);                                                // формируем строку
            int endOfLineIndex = sb.indexOf("\r\n");                            // определяем символы конца строки
            if (endOfLineIndex > 0) {                                            // если встречаем конец строки,
                String sbprint = sb.substring(0, endOfLineIndex);               // то извлекаем строку
                sb.delete(0, sb.length());                                      // и очищаем sb
                txtArduino.setText("Ответ от Arduino: " + sbprint);             // обновляем TextView
                btnOff.setEnabled(true);
                btnOn.setEnabled(true); 
            }
            //Log.d(TAG, "...Строка:"+ sb.toString() +  "Байт:" + msg.arg1 + "...");
            break;
        }
       };
      };
      btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();       // получаем локальный Bluetooth адаптер
     checkBTState();
 }

@Override
public void onPause() {
super.onPause();

Log.d(TAG, "...In onPause()...");

try     {
  btSocket.close();
} catch (IOException e2) {
  errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onPause() and failed to close socket." + e2.getMessage() + ".");
  }
 }

 private void checkBTState() {
// Check for Bluetooth support and then check to make sure it is turned on
// Emulator doesn't support Bluetooth and will return null
if(btAdapter==null) { 
  errorExit("Fatal Error", "Bluetooth не поддерживается");
} else {
  if (btAdapter.isEnabled()) {
    Log.d(TAG, "...Bluetooth включен...");
  } else {
    //Prompt user to turn on Bluetooth
    Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(btAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
    startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
  }
 }
}

private void errorExit(String title, String message){
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), title + " - " + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
finish();
}

  private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        mmSocket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        // Get the input and output streams, using temp objects because
        // member streams are final
        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) { }

        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }

     public void run() {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[256];  // buffer store for the stream
        int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

        // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
        while (true) {
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);        // Получаем кол-во байт и само собщение в байтовый массив "buffer"
                h.obtainMessage(RECIEVE_MESSAGE, bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();     // Отправляем в очередь сообщений Handler
            } catch (IOException e) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /* Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device */
    public void write(String message) {
        Log.d(TAG, "...Данные для отправки: " + message + "...");
        byte[] msgBuffer = message.getBytes();
        try {
            mmOutStream.write(msgBuffer);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "...Ошибка отправки данных: " + e.getMessage() + "...");     
          }
    }

    /* Call this from the main activity to shutdown the connection */
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }
}
```

public void sync_click(View v){

```
     address = F.getText().toString();
     Log.d(TAG, "...onResume - попытка соединения...");

        // Set up a pointer to the remote node using it's address.
        BluetoothDevice device = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);

        // Two things are needed to make a connection:
        //   A MAC address, which we got above.
        //   A Service ID or UUID.  In this case we are using the
        //     UUID for SPP.
        try {
          btSocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                   "In onResume() and socket create failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT); 
        toast.show();

        }

        // Discovery is resource intensive.  Make sure it isn't going on
        // when you attempt to connect and pass your message.
        btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        // Establish the connection.  This will block until it connects.
        Log.d(TAG, "...Соединяемся...");
        try {
          btSocket.connect();
          Log.d(TAG, "...Соединение установлено и готово к передачи данных...");
        } catch (IOException e) {
          try {
            btSocket.close();
          } catch (IOException e2) {
              Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                       "In onResume() and unable to close socket during connection failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT); 
            toast.show();
            }
        }

        // Create a data stream so we can talk to server.
        Log.d(TAG, "...Создание Socket...");

        mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(btSocket);
        mConnectedThread.start();

        synctext.setText("Синхронизированно");
        synctext.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
        s = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
        s.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        s.setEnabled(false);
        F.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        F.setEnabled(false);
        MACtext.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        MACtext.setEnabled(false);
        came.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        came.setEnabled(true);
        nice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);   
        nice.setEnabled(true);
        waittext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        waittext.setEnabled(true);
        o.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        o.setEnabled(true);
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
               "Синхронизировано", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT); 
        toast.show(); 
        p = 1;
}
```

Скинул основное код, суть программы такова что после событий onCreate, путём нажатия кнопки вызывается public void sync_click(View v). Далее если я выхожу из приложения то происходит краш.
Ниже привожу отрывок из LogCat

```
06-22 11:51:03.469: I/System.out(614): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-22 11:51:03.687: I/System.out(614): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-22 11:51:03.891: I/System.out(614): waiting for debugger to settle...
 06-22 11:51:04.098: I/System.out(614): debugger has settled (1324)
 06-22 11:52:06.687: I/Choreographer(614): Skipped 567 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
 06-22 11:52:07.247: D/libEGL(614): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
 06-22 11:52:07.247: D/(614): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x2a1264a8, tid 614
06-22 11:52:07.277: D/libEGL(614): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
06-22 11:52:07.287: D/libEGL(614): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
06-22 11:52:07.357: W/EGL_emulation(614): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
06-22 11:52:07.378: D/OpenGLRenderer(614): Enabling debug mode 0
06-22 11:53:15.387: D/bluetooth2(614): ...In onPause()...
06-22 11:53:30.658: D/AndroidRuntime(614): Shutting down VM
06-22 11:53:30.658: W/dalvikvm(614): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
 06-22 11:53:31.117: E/AndroidRuntime(614): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 06-22 11:53:31.117: E/AndroidRuntime(614): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {com.example.kgcontrol/com.example.kgcontrol.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
 06-22 11:53:31.117: E/AndroidRuntime(614):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2838)
 06-22 11:53:31.117: E/AndroidRuntime(614):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2794)
 06-22 11:53:31.117: E/AndroidRuntime(614):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2772)
 06-22 11:53:31.117: E/AndroidRuntime(614):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:130)
 06-22 11:53:31.117: E/AndroidRuntime(614):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1212)
 06-22 11:53:31.117: E/AndroidRuntime(614):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 06-22 11:53:31.117: E/AndroidRuntime(614):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 06-22 11:53:31.117: E/AndroidRuntime(614):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
 06-22 11:53:31.117: E/AndroidRuntime(614):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 06-22 11:53:31.117: E/AndroidRuntime(614):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 06-22 11:53:31.117: E/AndroidRuntime(614):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
 06-22 11:53:31.117: E/AndroidRuntime(614):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
06-22 11:53:31.117: E/AndroidRuntime(614):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-22 11:53:31.117: E/AndroidRuntime(614): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-22 11:53:31.117: E/AndroidRuntime(614):  at com.example.kgcontrol.MainActivity.onPause(MainActivity.java:288)
06-22 11:53:31.117: E/AndroidRuntime(614):  at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:5106)
 06-22 11:53:31.117: E/AndroidRuntime(614):     at a ndroid.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1225)
 06-22 11:53:31.117: E/AndroidRuntime(614):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2825)
06-22 11:53:31.117: E/AndroidRuntime(614):  ... 12 more
06-22 11:53:34.857: I/Process(614): Sending signal. PID: 614 SIG: 9
06-22 11:56:16.087: E/Trace(661): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
06-22 11:56:16.147: W/ActivityThread(661): Application com.example.kgcontrol is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
06-22 11:56:16.187: I/System.out(661): Sending WAIT chunk
06-22 11:56:16.387: I/dalvikvm(661): Debugger is active
06-22 11:56:16.587: I/System.out(661): Debugger has connected
06-22 11:56:16.587: I/System.out(661): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-22 11:56:16.797: I/System.out(661): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-22 11:56:16.997: I/System.out(661): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-22 11:56:17.200: I/System.out(661): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-22 11:56:17.397: I/System.out(661): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-22 11:56:17.603: I/System.out(661): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-22 11:56:17.797: I/System.out(661): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-22 11:56:18.007: I/System.out(661): debugger has settled (1316)
06-22 11:56:18.801: D/dalvikvm(661): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
06-22 11:58:54.417: I/Choreographer(661): Skipped 98 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-22 11:58:54.797: D/libEGL(661): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
06-22 11:58:54.807: D/(661): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x2a0da4e0, tid 661
06-22 11:58:54.807: D/libEGL(661): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
06-22 11:58:54.817: D/libEGL(661): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
06-22 11:58:54.867: W/EGL_emulation(661): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
06-22 11:58:54.877: D/OpenGLRenderer(661): Enabling debug mode 0
06-22 11:59:00.647: D/bluetooth2(661): ...In onPause()...
06-22 11:59:06.587: D/AndroidRuntime(661): Shutting down VM
06-22 11:59:06.587: W/dalvikvm(661): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
06-22 11:59:07.067: E/AndroidRuntime(661): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-22 11:59:07.067: E/AndroidRuntime(661): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {com.example.kgcontrol/com.example.kgcontrol.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
 06-22 11:59:07.067: E/AndroidRuntime(661):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2838)
  06-22 11:59:07.067: E/AndroidRuntime(661):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2794)
  06-22 11:59:07.067: E/AndroidRuntime(661):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2772)
  06-22 11:59:07.067: E/AndroidRuntime(661):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:130)
  06-22 11:59:07.067: E/AndroidRuntime(661):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1212)
  06-22 11:59:07.067: E/AndroidRuntime(661):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  06-22 11:59:07.067: E/AndroidRuntime(661):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
  06-22 11:59:07.067: E/AndroidRuntime(661):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
  06-22 11:59:07.067: E/AndroidRuntime(661):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  06-22 11:59:07.067: E/AndroidRuntime(661):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
  06-22 11:59:07.067: E/AndroidRuntime(661):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
  06-22 11:59:07.067: E/AndroidRuntime(661):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
  06-22 11:59:07.067: E/AndroidRuntime(661):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  06-22 11:59:07.067: E/AndroidRuntime(661): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
  06-22 11:59:07.067: E/AndroidRuntime(661):    at com.example.kgcontrol.MainActivity.onPause(MainActivity.java:288)
  06-22 11:59:07.067: E/AndroidRuntime(661):    at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:5106)
  06-22 11:59:07.067: E/AndroidRuntime(661):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1225)
  06-22 11:59:07.067: E/AndroidRuntime(661):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2825)
  06-22 11:59:07.067: E/AndroidRuntime(661):    ... 12 more
```

Comment: Покажите, что находится в `MainActivity` на 288 строке.

Comment: btSocket.close();

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NullPointerException` на этой строке свидетельствует о том, что `btSocket` равен `null`.

Comment: поправил, спасибо большое))